# Cannot successfully delete document in mongoose DB with DELETE or POST Request

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I am trying do delete employees in my mongoose database through my admin.ejs page.

So far I've tried to do with with a normal POST request and with DELETE using method-override but neither work.

// Attempt Without method-override

//Schema//

```
const empSchema = {
name: String,
number: String
  };

  const Employee = mongoose.model("Employee", empSchema);
```

//admin.ejs//

```
 <form action="/deleteEmp" method="POST" >
  <div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Delete Employee</button>
</form>
```

//app.js//

```
app.post("/deleteEmp", function(req, res) {
Employee.findOneAndDelete({name: req.params.name}, function(err, result) {

if(!err) {
    console.log('User Deleted');
    res.redirect("admin");
} else {
    console.log(err);
}
});

});
```

//Attempt with method-override//

//admin.ejs//

```
   <form method="POST" action="/deleteEmp?_method=DELETE">
  <div>
    <label>ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="id">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Delete Employee</button>
   </form>
```

//app.js//

```
  app.delete("/deleteEmp", function(req, res) {
  Employee.findOneAndDelete({name: req.params.name}, function(err, result) 
  {

   if(!err) {
    console.log('User Deleted');
    res.redirect("admin");
   } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
  });

  });
```

In my attempt without method override it will go through if it is set to POST method instead of DELETE but the employee is not deleted. If the method is set to DELETE it returns a cannot GET /deleteEMP

I didn't have any success with method-override, so I wonder if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can perform a delete operation through a POST request, it is recommended to use the proper http VERB (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE ..) for each case. So in your case i would use an AJAX delete request to delete the document.
By the way, the reason that your first option (action="/deleteEmp" method="POST") does not work is a mistake in your controller. Use `name: req.body.name` instead of `name: req.params.name`. The data you send is in the `body` of your request object.

Comment: It was the req.params, once I switched it to req.body the method-override worked just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"cannot GET /deleteEMP" indicates that u sent GET request. Try to send DELETE request from Postman or XMLHttpRequest(Ajax). HTML forms only support GET and POST as HTTP request methods.